# Create a program that if user were to type a chess-coordinate, and the mouse would transport to input while the screen is overlay in a grid

Tags: accessibility, coordinates, mouse, chess

Create a program that allows a user to type a chess-coordinate (i.e. G38), and the mouse will transport to that location while the screen is over-layered with a cartesian coordinate system to suit as a reference.

What language?

What classes do I need?
OOP or functional?

Is this re-inventing the wheel or is this new patentable idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: G38 isn't a chess coordinate :)